# InvalidOperationException because of different ObjectContext objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, objectcontext

I'm facing an issue I don't really understand with Entity Manager (C#). I'm kinda new at this stuff so please bear with my noobness ^^

I'm trying to create an instance of UserQuestion (which makes the link in the DataBase between the tables UserQuestionnaire and Question ; UserQuestionnaire linking a User and a Questionnaire).

So here is the code in question :

```
public static void Insert_Resultat_Question_BDD(Question q, double resultat) {
     DataSourceContainer bdd = new DataSourceContainer(); // initializes the Context
     User user = BLL.Users.Get_User_Connecté(); // Gets the connected user
     Questionnaire questionnaire = BLL.Questionnaires.Get_Questionnaire_En_Cours(); // Gets the questionnaire being taken
     UserQuestionnaire user_questionnaire = bdd.UserQuestionnaireSet.FirstOrDefault(i => i.User.id == user.id && i.Questionnaire.id == questionnaire.id); // Get the UserQuestionnaire object for the user and questionnaire above
     UserQuestion uq = new UserQuestion {  score = resultat * q.bareme, bareme = q.bareme, Question = q, UserQuestionnaire = user_questionnaire }; // Creates the object
     bdd.AddToUserQuestionSet(uq); // Add it to the table
     bdd.SaveChanges(); // Save
 }
```

I'm getting an error when creating the UserQuestion, because the UserQuestionnaire = user_questionnaire statement launches an InvalidOperationException because :
**"The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects."**

What I don't understand is that I only use 1 context ! (First line in the code I shared)

Can someone help me through this ? I don't really know what more to do :s

Thanks !

Comment: BLL is a folder in which I have put "business" classes (BLL = Business Logic Layer), like Questionnaires.cs and Users.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `BLL.Questionnaires.Get_Questionnaire_En_Cours()` uses its own ObjectContext.

Comment: Yes it does.

Basically, what this method does is read from a session variable the ID of the questionnaire being taken, then goes into the database to get the "Questionnaire" object (using a objectcontext) and returns it.


But I don't understand because even if questionnaire is handled with another object context, in the end the object I handle is user_questionnaire, and this one isn't used with another objectcontext.

Anyway, what should I do then ?

Comment: @Tahedoz: `uq` references `q` from the other context.  You should modify your BLL to work with an existing context.